# How to use typeshed with mypy?

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

I cloned [typeshed](https://github.com/python/typeshed) but I can't figure out how to tell mypy to use the type hints it contains, I see no option in mypy --help. The mypy repo does contain reference to the typeshed repo, but pip installing it doesn't not download it.

Comment: I think you need to copy the `.pyi` stubs you need into `/stubs`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Mypy comes bundled with typeshed by default, so you shouldn't need to do anything -- simply doing `pip install mypy` will install it correctly.

Note that typeshed is not a Python module, so it isn't possible to import it or otherwise access it from a Python program unless you literally look at the location in the filesystem the stubs are stored.

Comment: I looked install the mypy dir but couldn't find the stubs. Where are they ?

Comment: @e-satis: Typeshed is installed as data files by `setup.py`. On my system, that ends up being `C:\Python35\Lib\mypy\typeshed`.

Answer (score 5):

Since version *0.4.6* `mypy` has the option `--custom-typeshed`:

```
mypy --py2 --custom-typeshed ~/REPOS/PYTHON/mypy/typeshed my-thing.py
```

See [command line reference](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_line.html#advanced-flags) for the documentation and [Issue 2323](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/2323) for the gory details.

Comment: It is now `--custom-typeshed-dir`.