# MyPy - how do you actually use typeshed stubs in annotations?

Tags: python, mypy

Note: [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38934841/8378419) does NOT answer my question. It merely restates what I already have read.

How is this supposed to work? Everything I read says `typeshed` is bundled with `MyPy` and contains stubs for third party libraries. I have `MyPy` installed and running in a virtualenv and I'm trying to use it to type `Flask` code but I'm just not getting it.

I have a background in TypeScript, and I was looking for something similar but I don't understand how we are supposed to use stubs with `MyPy`. For example, I have this function:

```
def create_app(config_name="default"):
    app: Flask = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(Configuration)
    CORS(app)
    register_extensions(app)
    register_blueprints(app)

    @app.route("/health")
    def health_check():
        return json.dumps({"status": "up"})

    return app
```

Pretty standard for Flask, but with strict disallow any settings this becomes an unsalvageable mess. What is the type of app? I know that `typeshed` [has stubs for flask](https://github.com/python/typeshed/tree/master/third_party/2and3/flask) but I cannot figure out how to actually utilize those stubs. The `typeshed` docs say:

> If you're just using mypy (or pytype or PyCharm), as opposed to developing it, you don't need to interact with the typeshed repo at all: a copy of typeshed is bundled with mypy.

So I'm assuming I do not need to import the types, the docs don't make any mention of importing them anyway.

For example, there is a stub called `app.pyi` but if I annotate the function like this:

```
def create_app(config_name="default") -> app:
```

I get the error `name app is not defined`. If I import it:

```
from typeshed import app
```

I get the error `Return type becomes any due to an unfollowed import` which, as far as I can tell, means there is no such module `typeshed` or it has no member called `app`.

So how do I actually get access to these `typeshed` stubs? My last resort is to simply clone the `typeshed` repo and point `mypy` to it as a custom typeshed dir, but I'd really like to do things the proper way.

Comment: Wouldn't the type be `Flask`?

Comment: wow I feel like a big dummy .-. thanks

Answer (score 3):

Although for this specific instance you can just use imports from the package itself, there are cases where you do need to import types from `typeshed` for annotations (in my case it was trying to use the wsgi type [`StartResponse`](https://github.com/python/mypy/blob/e266cdf04f7ded2ee2da89b5912402df52a8e254/mypy/typeshed/stdlib/_typeshed/wsgi.pyi#L9).

These are importable, but only inside an `if TYPE_CHECKING:` block like so:

```py
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from _typeshed.wsgi import StartResponse

def application(environ: Dict, start_response: "StartResponse"):
    # etc
```

This only works (and should only be necessary) for types found in the [mypy/typeshed/stdlib/_typeshed](https://github.com/python/mypy/tree/e266cdf04f7ded2ee2da89b5912402df52a8e254/mypy/typeshed/stdlib/_typeshed) directory.